# Export table to excel file with pagination and filters

Tags: angular, excel, typescript, pagination, datasource

I haven't found anything online and was hoping someone here could help me.

In my application I have a table complete with pagination and column by column filters, the problem is that if I now go to create an excel file with these functions

**Excel-service-ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelService {

  constructor() { }

  public exportAsExcelFile(tableid:string, name?: string): void {
    const timeSpan = new Date().toISOString();
    const fileName = `${name}-${timeSpan}`;
    const targetTableElm = document.getElementById(tableid);
    const wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(targetTableElm, { sheet: name } as
 XLSX.Table2SheetOpts);
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, `${fileName}.xlsx`);
  }

  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_exported'+ EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
createExcelFile(){
    this.excelservice.exportAsExcelFile('excel-table','Matricola' + Date.now())
  }
```

[This is my table, in this case it will export in the excel only this 5 rows, Instead of exporting all 4397 of them (I blacked out the data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDuo4.png)

**It only exports the first 5 or 10 filtered or paginated results.**

**What I would like is that if I filter by a column in my table I get 300 results, it prints 300 rows in Excel, not 5 which are actually visible to the user due to pagination.**

*Edit: the solution you provided give me this error :* [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx4iW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `XLSX.utils.table_to_book` you have to use `XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet` and provide the data you want to export. `table_to_book` method will only export that table data which is the page it showing. So your code would be like this:

```
public exportAsExcelFile(data: { [key: string]: any }[], name?: string): void {
    const timeSpan = new Date().toISOString();
    const fileName = `${name}-${timeSpan}`;
    const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
    const workbook = { Sheets: { data: worksheet }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(workbook, {
      bookType: "xlsx",
      type: "array",
    });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, `${fileName}.xlsx`);
}
```

Instead of data, you provide this method with all data you want to export.

Comment: The solution you provided is not working, it gives me the error you can see in the edit of my question at the bottom.

Comment: You're right my code was incomplete. I've edited my code.

Comment: On the json_to_sheet(data) is giving me the same error as before.

Do you know why?

Comment: json_to_sheet ask for an object, we're passing him an {[key: string] : any}

Comment: `json_to_sheet` method needs an array as input. data type must be `{ [key: string]: any }[]`

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

**TS File**

```
public exportTable() {
Utility.exportTableToExcel(this.dataSource.filteredData);}
```

**Save2Excel**

```
static exportTableToExcel(data: { [key: string]: any }[], name?: string) {
let { sheetName, fileName } = getFileName(name!);
const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
const workbook = { Sheets: { data: worksheet }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `${fileName}.xlsx`);}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).